# c# - remove focus from ListViewItem

Tags: c#, listview, focus, listviewitem

I am working on a project (simple phone book) for personal use. Here you can take a look how it looks like:

**IMAGE**: http://s24.postimg.org/e37syu5x1/screenshot_66.png

So, first of all you have to type something in the txtSearch and then press the Search button next to it. That button does the following:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        txtSearch_TextChanged();
    }
```

where **txtSearch_TextChanged();** is:

```
 void txtSearch_TextChanged()
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            //Selected = true, won't show until the listview has focus, but setting it to true puts it in the
            //SelectedItems collection.
            if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                item.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                item.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                item.Selected = false;
                item.BackColor = Color.White;
                item.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }

        }
        //When the selection is narrowed to one the user can stop typing
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            listView1.Focus();                  
        }

    }
```

The problem is that the contact I was searching for remains selected (or focused?) - in this case it is **4** since I was searching for **4**.

I have tried to attach **Unfocus()** to **RefreshAll()** but unfortunately with no success:

```
void Unfocus()
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].Selected = false;
        }
        if (listView1.FocusedItem != null)
        {
            listView1.FocusedItem.Focused = false;
        }
    }

void RefreshAll()
    {
            txtSearch.Text = "";
            UserCount();
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
            textBox5.Text = "";
            textBox6.Text = "";
            dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
            textBox2.ReadOnly = false;
            textBox3.ReadOnly = false;
            textBox4.ReadOnly = false;
            textBox5.ReadOnly = false;
            textBox6.ReadOnly = false;
            dateTimePicker1.Enabled = true;
            toolStripEdit.Enabled = false;
            Unfocus();

    }
```

Also, I would like the following: when I search for a contact and I find it, it appears as the only item in the listview (the listview should contain no other contact, except the one I was searching for (successfully)). In this case, it would be **4**. By the way, it should look like this:

**IMAGE**: http://s24.postimg.org/r8nb4xzsl/screenshot_66.png

When it comes to this, after numerous tries I am stuck at:

```
listView1.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
listView1.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Try to be more descriptive in suggesting your approach so that it can be easily understandable. If there is not much to be described then think of adding a comment instead of adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the problem was that I haven't seen few lines of code which used to assign selected item some different color... I removed that and everything is OK now.